# iOS: how to implement a shared method for two API callbacks returning the same result/error set

Tags: ios, objective-c, api, asynchronous, callback

I am writing a **client APP** calling an API and processing the results in a a callback method.

The method is defined as follows:

```
//Current implementation

[_myAPIInterface dataByName:name withCallback:^(NSError *error, NSDictionary *result) {
        //Method body.. processing the results

        if (error) {
            return;
        }
        else{
            [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        }
 }];
```

I would like to be able to define teh callBack block as a separate function that I can call so whenever I call the API as client passing different paramenters (e.g. by name, by age) I can pass the same block/method to process the results and avoid implementing it twice.

```
//Desired implementation/approach
[_myAPIInterface dataByName:name withCallback:^(NSError *error, NSDictionary *result) {
      [self sharedMethod:error :results];   
 }];

[_myAPIInterface dataByAge:age withCallback:^(NSError *error, NSDictionary *result) {
      [self sharedMethod:error :results];   
 }];
```

- is the desired implementation possible at all?
- is it possible to define a **sharedMethod** that gets called in the callback block? If so how should I `approach/implement` it?

Comment: I don't really understand your question. Are you the API client or provider? What do you mean by "recycling" the block? Do you mean the type of the block? And regarding your `sharedMethod`: Sure, why shouldn't it be possible to declare/implement this method? Please tell us what *specific* problems you are facing...

Comment: And, by the way, it's not good practice to have unnamed method parameters (like in your `sharedMethod`).

Comment: thanks! I have modified the question.. is it more clear now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can assign the block to a variable and pass that variable to each method.

```
void (^callback)(NSError *, NSDictionary *) = ^(NSError *error, NSDictionary *result) {
    //Method body.. processing the results

    if (error) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        [self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    }
};

[_myAPIInterface dataByName:name withCallback:callback];
[_myAPIInterface dataByAge:age withCallback:callback];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are just calling a method from a block, that is fine, there is nothing special about it. You were already calling the `stopAnimating` method from the block.

Comment: ...in fact I am doing a bit more but I simplified this to make it SO friendly. I am changing text/description values in several UI elements by processing the JSON result set that I get as dictionary..

Comment: It does not make any difference how much you are doing.